# Wicked pdf rendering large table content on next page - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

i am using wickedpdf to generate pdf in my project.

The html page for which the pdf is generated contains some basic information and a table.
When the table has only less rows and less content, it renders correctly below the basic info section.
[image]

As you can see in the above image, basic info (Vienna, Virgnia) is displayed and below it the table is displayed.

The problem is when the table has more rows/ content is large. Then the whole table is moved to next page in the pdf.

[image: enter code here]

There is a lot. of blank space. I want to remove this.

I want the table to be displayed below the basic info rather than moving it to the next page in the pdf. Only the rows that does not fit in the current page should be displayed in the next page in the pdf.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Was having similar issue with boostrap responsive table class, after removing it it break properly into 2 page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).